# My Alternator Case to Battery Negative is reading 12 vdc and same for the Case to Positive side

Tags: battery, alternator, altima, voltage, ground

just had tranny replaced last week.  The alternator that was on the car had been replaced in May of this year.  I drove car for at least 1000 miles since the tranny was replaced.  But, last night the alternator went out, so I replaced it.  WIthin a few miles, the replacement alternator went out both saying they have a bad voltage regulator. I am suspicious about the wiring for the transaxle and possible bad ground or something .  I just charged with my battery charger and check the voltage across battery which is less than 12.2 because it is not being charged but, what does not make sense is the 12.09 vdc between ALt case and battery positive and 12.12 vdc between ALT case and bat neg.  What in the world is going on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What is the voltage at the battery while the engine is running?

Comment: If you have 12v between case and bat neg then you have a broken earh cable.

Comment: Is there a voltage between the alternator case and the engine block?